# Как написать код, что бы он не выводил последнюю запятую?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

```
n = int(input('Сколько чисел нужно вывести?\nКол-во цифрой:'))
if n == 0:
    print(0)
else:
    a, b = 0, 1
    _ = 0
    while _ < n:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            _ += 1
            print(a, end=',')
        a, b = b, a + b
```

вывод такой:

```
Сколько чисел нужно вывести?
Кол-во цифрой:4
0,2,8,34,
```

Как сделать  так:

```
Сколько чисел нужно вывести?
Кол-во цифрой:4
0,2,8,34
```

Comment: Лучше не использовать `_` для выражений с логикой :) Этот символ буквально используется для мест, где говорится, что значение не нужно, типа: `for _ in range(...)` или `a, _, c = 1, 2, 3`. В первом нам не нужен индекс, но нужны итерации, во втором мы распаковываем в переменные, но нужны только 1 и 3 значение

Answer (score 2):

Например, выводить запятую перед числами, нужно только проверять, чтобы вывести для тех, что после первого будут

```
n = int(input('Сколько чисел нужно вывести?\nКол-во цифрой:'))
if n == 0:
    print(0)
else:
    a, b = 0, 1
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            i += 1
            if i > 1:
                print(',', end='')
            print(a, end='')
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input('Сколько чисел нужно вывести?\nКол-во цифрой:'))
if n == 0:
    print(0)
else:
    a, b = 0, 1
    _ = 0
    while _ < n:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            _ += 1
            if _ != n:
                print(a, end=',')
            else:
                print(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Не стоит называть переменную _

Будет лучше придумать более осмысленное название.